# Rails 4 in Action: unable to push code to heroku, sh: 2: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am working through the [Rails 4 In Action](https://www.manning.com/books/rails-4-in-action) Book.  I am on **chapter 13: Deployment**,  page 457 where you push your code up to heroku:

```
git push heroku master
```

It appears to successfully grab all the needed gems as it gets to this part:

```
remote:        Bundle complete! 27 Gemfile dependencies, 90 gems now installed.
remote:        Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
remote:        Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
remote:        Bundle completed (29.18s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache
```

But then right after that it blows up and says this:

```
remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks
remote: sh: 2: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
remote: sh: 2: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
remote:  !
remote:  !     Could not detect rake tasks
remote:  !     ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
remote:  !     and using the production group of your Gemfile.
remote:  !     rake aborted!
remote:  !     LoadError: cannot load such file -- net/ssh
```

I did what it suggested and ran `bundle exec rake -P`.  Here was the output from that:

```
rake aborted!

LoadError: cannot load such file -- net/ssh
```

This is the tough part when working through a tutorial book.  I do not think I missed any steps.  I'm not sure what to do here.  Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out and hope this helps anyone else having the same issue.

What eventually did it for me was that I had to update the `fog` gem.  The book has you use version `1.29.0`.  For whatever reason: that version was not working for me.

In my `Gemfile` I simply put `gem "fog"`, deleted my `Gemfile.lock` and ran `bundle` so that it would go out and grab the latest version.

Afterwards I looked inside the `Gemfile.lock` and noticed it grabbed the `fog` version of `1.38.0`.  Now when I ran `git push heroku master` it worked.

What led me to try out updating `fog` was [this issue on the fog github page](https://github.com/fog/fog/issues/3765).

In case anyone was curious: I was using `rails 4.2.1`, as well as `ruby 2.2.1` as the book tells you to.